# stack level too deep after upgrading to rails 3.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am in the process of upgrading my application to the latest rails and have been strugling with a stack level too deep error. This error happens when I make an ajax request from my model. Here is the error and relevant controller/model code:

**error**

```
[679c54ab63bbaad55d7a1bd1fd9246d7] [127.0.0.1] Processing by CoachesController#new as */*
[679c54ab63bbaad55d7a1bd1fd9246d7] [127.0.0.1]   Parameters: {"date"=>"2013-06-11", "athlete_id"=>"2"}
[679c54ab63bbaad55d7a1bd1fd9246d7] [127.0.0.1]   User Load (24.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
[679c54ab63bbaad55d7a1bd1fd9246d7] [127.0.0.1]   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
[679c54ab63bbaad55d7a1bd1fd9246d7] [127.0.0.1]    (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "log_entries" WHERE "log_entries"."athlete_id" = 2 AND (date == '2013-06-11')
[679c54ab63bbaad55d7a1bd1fd9246d7] [127.0.0.1] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 60ms
[679c54ab63bbaad55d7a1bd1fd9246d7] [127.0.0.1] 
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70
```

**Controller**

```
   def new
@athlete = User.find_by_id(params[:athlete_id])   #this is different in normal controller(non coach)
@date = Date.parse(params[:date])
if LogEntry.cal_entry(@date, @athlete.id).size == 0 #check to see if entry exists
  @log_entry = @athlete.log_entries.build
  @log_entry1 = @log_entry.clone
  @workouts = @log_entry.workouts.build
  planned_workouts = @workouts.planned_workouts.build
  n = 1
  1.times do #do not generate more than the zone 1 
    planned_workouts.planned_workout_times.build(:zone => n)
    n += 2
  end
  completed_workouts = @workouts.completed_workouts.build
  n = 1
  1.times do
    completed_workouts.workout_times.build(:zone => n)
    n += 2
  end

else                                                #use already existing LogEntry
  @log_entry1 = LogEntry.cal_entry(@date, @athlete.id).first
  @log_entry = @athlete.log_entries.build
  @log_entry = @log_entry1.clone
  @workouts = @log_entry1.workouts.build
  planned_workouts = @workouts.planned_workouts.build
  n = 1 
  1.times do
    planned_workouts.planned_workout_times.build(:zone => n)
    n += 2
  end
  completed_workouts = @workouts.completed_workouts.build
  n = 1
  1.times do
    completed_workouts.workout_times.build(:zone => n)
    n += 2
  end 
end
```

^^ this is where the error seems to occur when the .cal_entry model function is called

**Model**

```
  scope :log_entry_for_date, lambda { |date1| where('date == ?', date1)}
  scope :log_entry_for_athlete, lambda { |athlete_id| where(:athlete_id => athlete_id)}

  def self.cal_entry(date, athlete_id)
    log_entry_for_date(date).log_entry_for_athlete(athlete_id).includes({:workouts => {:completed_workouts => :workout_times}})
  end
```

Now this worked perfectly in rails 3.0 but displays the error immediately after upgrading. I tried upgrading to rails 3.2 but the error is still there.

ruby 1.9.3p429

rails 3.2.0

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `LogEntry.cal_entry(@date, @athlete.id).size` is actually executing, according to the sql being spit out. Can you include the entire controller method?

Comment: just added the entire method.

Comment: by removing lines of code it seems to be `@workouts = @log_entry.workouts.build` that is creating the stack level too deep error, my model is organized so each log_entry has many workouts, why would this be a problem?

Comment: Note that `find_by_id` and `find` are identical, the `_by_id` is implied. `User.find_by_id(params[:athlete_id])` should be `User.find(params[:athlete_id])`. Also, I'm not sure why you're using `n` or `1.times` or `n += 2`. These lines have no affect on your code. Your method should really look like this: http://pastebin.com/GX45T4pi

Comment: thanks! so much cleaner. I originally had the iterations because I was generating a couple workout_time fields but then decided to only display one for now rendering that code pointless. Thanks, I am still learning cleaner code is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

It seems the error was caused by a poorly named method in the workouts model named "method" (for instructions) I guess it wasn't a problem till the upgrade.